# Will Google follow HTML refresh?

Tags: redirects, search-engines

I want to move my current Tumblr blog to static HTML blog. Currently I am using a custom domain, I am planning on doing the move when Google sees domain name change. I am considering two options:

1. Buying a hosting service
2. Using GitHub pages

Buying a hosting service would probably mean I am going to pay for lots of things that I don't need like PHP, MySQL, e-mail service etc. On the other hand, if I use GitHub pages, I can't use *.htaccess* file to make 301 redirects. I want to change my URL structure and this is important to me.

I was wondering if I use:

```
<meta http-equiv=refresh content="0; url=http://example.com/newurl" />
```

Would Google see it as 301 redirect, so that I won't use my search engine value?

Comment: Google strongly recommends *not* using meta refreshes to redirect

Answer (score 1):

A [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) is not seen as a [301 redirect](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en), which is an [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) that tells client applications and search engines that a page has *permanently* moved to a new location. The meta refresh would simply *refresh* the page to the specified URL each time the page is loaded.

See this GitHub help doc for [setting up a custom domain with pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages).

Answer (score 1):

[This was discussed on webmasterworld](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum3/17643.htm).  doc_z says:

> As far as I know, Google follows these redirections and PR is passed. Google doesn't distinguish between these pages. The content is taken from the target page.

[Here is an article about it on dannytalk.com](http://www.dannytalk.com/301-meta-refresh-redirects-how-google-and-yahoo-sees-it/) which says:

> It appears that a meta refresh delay of 0 or 1 second will be considered as a 301 redirect and anything longer is considered a 302.

[Google itself recommends against using meta refresh redirects](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en):

> This meta tag sends the user to a new URL after a certain amount of time, and is sometimes used as a simple form of redirection. However, it is not supported by all browsers and can be confusing to the user. The W3C [recommends that this tag not be used](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#meta-element). We recommend using a server-side 301 redirect instead.

Comment: The discussion in first link (from 2003) doesn't seem very reliable...I would stick with the last sentence quoted from Google (i.e., use a 301 redirect).